# Error when Downloading Android Things image for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things, android-things-console

I am trying to download an *Android Things* image for *Raspberry Pi 3* and I get this `403 Forbidden` error. What can I do?

```
What do you want to do?
1 - Install Android Things and optionally set up Wi-Fi
2 - Set up Wi-Fi on an existing Android Things device
1
What hardware are you using?
1 - Raspberry Pi 3
2 - NXP Pico i.MX7D
1
You chose Raspberry Pi 3.

Setting up required tools...
Fetching additional configuration...
Downloading platform tools...
4.74 MB/4.74 MB
Unzipping platform tools...
Finished setting up required tools.

Raspberry Pi 3
Do you want to use the default image or a custom image?
1 - Default image: Used for development purposes. No access to the Android
Things Console features such as metrics, crash reports, and OTA updates.
2 - Custom image: Upload your custom image for full device development and
management with all Android Things Console features.
1
Downloading Android Things image...
could not download image: unable to download image: error downloading file: error downloading file: error downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/things-images/images/iot_rpi3.img.zip: 403 Forbidden
Press [Enter] to quit.
```

Comment: What's your host OS?

Comment: @Onik I use Windows

Answer (score 3):

There is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174576244) on that... I also got the same result on my Mac.

In the meantime, you can do it manually by creating a new project in the [Console](https://developer.android.com/things/console), building a blank image and [flashing](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/windows.md) it into a microSD card. Then follow the [setup instructions](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi#step_2_connect_the_hardware).

In order to build an image click on the project's model ID (*see the picture below*) and follow the configuration steps.

[image]

Once built, the image can be downloaded.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These default images and tools are not longer available. You can now only flash your device using factory images for your console product.

I would also recommend reviewing the latest information on the [FAQ page](https://developer.android.com/things/faq) to learn more about the Android Things platform status.